# Apache Spark on client

Tags: apache-spark

I was wondering if it makes sense to install spark just on the client side without any clusters. A client device can be a laptop/desktop/mobile device. Can we put spark on one of these devices and leverage the libraries of spark.

Comment: Not sure what is the question, but spark is certainly can be used on a single machine (there are nice tools like Zeppelin and Jupyter with Spark kernel/service which make it easy to experiment with).

Comment: So my understanding of Spark is that if an application is written in SPARK, it needs a cluster manager which would be YARN/Mesos and this manager does the resource management and scheduling  of jobs to the nodes in the cluster. If there is no cluster then we wont be using the full functionality of spark right??

Comment: So spark can run on a cluster in absence of Mesos or Yarn just stand alone. You can also run spark on a laptop for prototyping and learning. running on a single machine you arent leveraging sparks distributed processing capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Spark runs great on a single (client) machine.

```
$spark-shell --master local[*]
```

or

```
$spark-submit --master local[*] --class "MyApp" MyApp.jar
```

Comment: Let me give an example. Suppose there is a machine learning algorithm that is implemented in some language. If I use that algorithm to run  a workload(which might do some training, classification) and calculate the power and performance and if i then install SPARK on the client machine and do the same thing using SPARK's MLLib, then due to the overload of installing SPARK, the power and performance maybe actually lower than the previous case right?

Comment: If you write some algorithm in C and then the same thing in Spark I would assume yes you are correct the C version will run faster on a single machine but I have no data (grin) to back me up. The purpose of Spark is to give you a "write it once, run it across a cluster" framework that can handle truly big data problems; this is where you are expected to save time. That said, I've been using Spark for smaller problems (just to learn) and it runs plenty fast on my laptop.

Comment: Ya even i think that the best use for SPARK comes out when it is used for computing and processing big data. Even though its good for a client device I don't think it makes sense to install SPARK on a client when we have no intention to use it on a cluster especially if you consider a mobile device because of the overhead that SPARK comes with.